# I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and now my computer won't boot from the hard drive.

Tags: 14.04, boot

The hard drive doesn't even show up on the Boot Sequence. I tried adding the hard drive as a boot option but it says that it does not exist. I also checked and the computer is set to UEFI mode. It loads and runs Ubuntu just fine from the thumb drive, but it won't boot the installed version of Ubuntu. I even double loaded to images of it side by side as someone else suggested. Still won't work. I used Gparted to flag the main Ubuntu partition as the boot as well and that did nothing. Help! I need this computer back!

Thanks,
Colin

Comment: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15561322/)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in the end, I had to reinstall 14.04 (erasing all previous versions, but without the encryption) while I was in the Flash Drive version of Ubuntu. Then I ran boot-repair. Then I shut the computer down and removed my thumb drive. Then I started the computer and it worked. Not sure which step was the winner this time, but when I tried the exact same set of steps outside the thumb drive driven Ubuntu environment and when I tried to do the "encrypted" version of the install, it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

I also have an error when I install install Windows on Ubuntu, solution:

1. Reinstall a installation boot disc or usp on system
2. Select the disc which is inserted into system on step 1
3. During booting it will ask install or use only mode, choose and click use only mode
4. When Ubuntu GUI appears open software center
5. Search a boot repair tool software then install
6. Open a bootrepair software, choose 2nd option to repair the grub booting program